# PNG image vs CSS shapes

Tags: css, vector, png, shapes

Say orange_square.png is a vector image of an orange coloured square:

`<img src='orange_square.jpg'>`

versus a css generated square:

```
<div style='height:20px;width:20px;background-color:orange'></div>
```

Which will be sharper? It'd also be helpful if you could offer the advantages and disadvantages of each solution.

Comment: check this article [https://www.growfox.co.uk/blog/5-reasons-you-should-be-using-svgs-over-pngs](https://www.growfox.co.uk/blog/5-reasons-you-should-be-using-svgs-over-pngs)